# Changing Bitcoin Wallet Address Range for Plutus.py

Tags: python, bitcoin, private-key

I am working with the following script from https://github.com/Isaacdelly/Plutus/blob/master/plutus.py

The script works for wallet addresses in the 2^160 range.  I am curious where in the script I can change this to look at the 2^128 range or 2^n range. Would it be possible to even have a window? Like 2^0 - 2^100?

Not trying to do anything malicious, just trying to get data to show that even selecting ranges is futile due to the large number of addresses.

```
 # Plutus Bitcoin Brute Forcer
# Made by Isaac Delly
# https://github.com/Isaacdelly/Plutus

try:
    import sys
    import os
    import time
    import hashlib
    import binascii
    import multiprocessing
    from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
    import threading
    import base58
    import ecdsa
    import requests
except ImportError:
    import subprocess
    subprocess.check_call(["python", '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'base58==1.0.0'])
    subprocess.check_call(["python", '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'ecdsa==0.13'])
    subprocess.check_call(["python", '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'requests==2.19.1'])
    import base58
    import ecdsa
    import requests

def generate_private_key():
    return binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32)).decode('utf-8')

def private_key_to_WIF(private_key):
    var80 = "80" + str(private_key) 
    var = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(var80)).hexdigest())).hexdigest()
    return str(base58.b58encode(binascii.unhexlify(str(var80) + str(var[0:8]))), 'utf-8')

def private_key_to_public_key(private_key):
    sign = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(binascii.unhexlify(private_key), curve = ecdsa.SECP256k1)
    return ('04' + binascii.hexlify(sign.verifying_key.to_string()).decode('utf-8'))

def public_key_to_address(public_key):
    alphabet = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    count = 0; val = 0
    var = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
    var.update(hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(public_key.encode())).digest())
    doublehash = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(('00' + var.hexdigest()).encode())).digest()).hexdigest()
    address = '00' + var.hexdigest() + doublehash[0:8]
    for char in address:
        if (char != '0'):
            break
        count += 1
    count = count // 2
    n = int(address, 16)
    output = []
    while (n > 0):
        n, remainder = divmod (n, 58)
        output.append(alphabet[remainder])
    while (val < count):
        output.append(alphabet[0])
        val += 1
    return ''.join(output[::-1])

def get_balance(address):
    try:
        response = requests.get("https://bitaps.com/api/address/" + str(address))
        return int(response.json()['balance']) 
    except:
        return -1

def data_export(queue):
    while True:
        private_key = generate_private_key()
        public_key = private_key_to_public_key(private_key)
        address = public_key_to_address(public_key)
        data = (private_key, address)
        queue.put(data, block = False)

def worker(queue):
    while True:
        if not queue.empty():
            data = queue.get(block = True)
            balance = get_balance(data[1])
            process(data, balance)

def process(data, balance):
    private_key = data[0]
    address = data[1]
    if (balance == 0):
        print("{:<34}".format(str(address)) + ": " + str(balance))
    if (balance > 0):
        file = open("plutus.txt","a")
        file.write("address: " + str(address) + "\n" +
                   "private key: " + str(private_key) + "\n" +
                   "WIF private key: " + str(private_key_to_WIF(private_key)) + "\n" +
                   "public key: " + str(private_key_to_public_key(private_key)).upper() + "\n" +
                   "balance: " + str(balance) + "\n\n")
        file.close()

def thread(iterator):
    processes = []
    data = Queue()
    data_factory = Process(target = data_export, args = (data,))
    data_factory.daemon = True
    processes.append(data_factory)
    data_factory.start()
    work = Process(target = worker, args = (data,))
    work.daemon = True
    processes.append(work)
    work.start()
    data_factory.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        pool = ThreadPool(processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()*2)
        pool.map(thread, range(0, 10))
    except:
        pool.close()
        exit()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding the purpose of the 2^160 bit range.

Each standard bitcoin address is tied to the HASH160 of the public key. A HASH160 is 160 bits long, which is why your search space is 2^160. If you are able to find two private keys for which the HASH160 of the public keys are equal, any of those two private keys can spend coins sent to that address.

Searching a smaller space does not make sense since you are no longer searching for bitcoin addresses. If you just want to search random hash functions, then you simply need to replace RIPEMD160 hash function with another one that has an output in whatever bitsize you wish to search.

Note that if you do that, the rest of the code talking about checking balances etc. will be of no use, since your output will no longer be a bitcoin address.